# Maya 2018 licensing issues on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation

After spending a while trawling through various websites on the internet, following breadcrumbs and satisfying missing several annoying dependencies, I was able to finally 'install' Autodesk Maya (Educational version) on my Ubuntu system. However, upon trying to run the binary via the terminal I get an error that tells me that a licensing error occurred and that it failed to authorize the license.

After some digging around, a website told me to run the following command:

`$ /usr/autodesk/maya2018/bin/adlmreg -i S <Product_Key> <Product_Key> 2018.0.0.F <serialNum> /var/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/Maya2018/MayaConfig.pit`

This doesn't appear to work and just gives me the following error:

`libadlmutil.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, I've checked file names to make certain they exist (which they do!) I've checked file paths and I'm certain I've got them correct.

I took a long hiatus from anything Linux related before coming back recently with the intent of taking it a bit more seriously. I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right, but I get the feeling I've made a rookie mistake here.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you've installed a binary that is not meant for Ubuntu 20.04. That binary has been compiled against various libraries, and obviously you did not install a prerequisite called "libadlmutil.so". Maybe you did, but it has a different version. The name "maya 2018" might hint at Ubuntu 18.04, whose libraries still may in sync with it. [Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2409547)  is a short thread from someone with the same (unsolved) problem. Does [this](https://gist.github.com/borgfriend/b83467639cb8039dc79974bf780a4994) gist help you?

Comment: If you get no help here, I'd suggest asking the folks at Maya. They're more likely to know than others.

Comment: See if the shared library is provided by a package `dpkg -S libadlmutil.so`.

Comment: @waltinator I've just tried that - this is what the terminal returns:
`adlmapps14: /opt/Autodesk/Adlm/R14/lib64/libadlmutil.so`
`adlmapps14: /opt/Autodesk/Adlm/R14/lib64/libadlmutil.so.14.0.23`
`adlmapps14: /opt/Autodesk/Adlm/R14/lib64/libadlmutil.so.14.0`

I've tried navigating to that directory using the file explorer, but the /lib64 under /R14 doesn't appear to exist - I presume I have to install them?
I'm not too familiar with dpkg

Comment: @waltinator Please disregard my previous comment, I've found that the libadlm.so exists in the installation, I copied it to the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory, but then found that the file also exists in a directory in the Maya installation, though why the system is unable to see/use it I'm not sure (though that could just be me being a noob)

Nevertheless, I've been able to get one step further - now I just need to figure out what this next error is